# How do I move Ubuntu dock to bottom on Ubuntu 17.10 and later?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Just upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10.

Please help me to shift the side bar (aka Ubuntu Dock) to bottom.

I tried running the following command which used to work with older Ubuntu releases

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

but it's not working.

Comment: The reason the command you tried does not work is that it adjust the settings of Unity, the interface that Ubuntu used to use before switching to GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 35):

Go to System Settings and Select Dock from the Left Sidebar. In here, you'll see the option to move the Launcher (it's called Dock in Ubuntu 17.10) to bottom or to the right.
[image]

Comment: If you have multiple monitors, you can choose which monitor the dock will appear on in the same place.

Answer (score 13):

In *Settings*, select *Dock* and you'll see a "Position on screen" option.

(Please note that Unity has been replaced by GNOME since Ubuntu 17.10.)

The corresponding `gsettings` command would be:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position BOTTOM
```

(In place of `BOTTOM` you can set any of the following options: `LEFT` (default), `RIGHT` and `TOP`.)

Answer (score 4):

It is in "Appearance" menu in Ubuntu 20.04:

[image]