# How to customize desktop

Tags: desktop-environments

I'm very new to Linux and am having trouble understanding how to customize my desktop. I would love to have my desktop look like an image provided below, but I'm confused how to do so. Is that icon bar a desklet? What is it that is needed to add this to my desktop?

[image]

Comment: What's your Ubuntu  version and flavour (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE etc.)?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 Unity

Comment: Have you installed Unity separately? Ubuntu 18.04 comes with GNOME by default. Could you add a screenshot of your desktop as it looks right now?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean Unity. I meant Gnome. Everything is a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @pomsky Unity 7.5 is automatically installed when you upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity 7) to Ubuntu 18.04. Not sure about 17.04 or 17.10 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things you can do to get a desktop similar to the one in the screenshot.

1. **Move Ubuntu dock to bottom from left**: follow [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966927/how-to-shift-side-bar-ubuntu-dock-to-bottom-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-later)
2. **Make the dock flexible instead of fixed-length**: Run the following command in Terminal

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
   ```

   ([source](http://gsettings%20set%20org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock%20extend-height%20false))
3. **Install and use Arc theme**: The application theme in the screenshot looks like the popular Arc theme. Install it first by running

   ```
   sudo apt install arc-theme
   ```

   Then install *(GNOME) Tweaks* by running

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```

   Finally, launch Tweaks and select Arc for application theme in Appearance section.