# taskbar cannot be moved to bottom + FSL installation not possible

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I just installed Ubuntu on a Windows (dual-use) computer and trying to change the position of the task bar with

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

and have no response from Computer. Is sth ( a driver, an app?) missing?

Also, trying install FSL with Ubuntu 18.04 (installed Python as recommended) and after fslinstaller.py --> "command not found" although I downloaded it.

Does anyone have an idea how to help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shift side bar (Ubuntu dock) to bottom on Ubuntu 17.10 and later](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966927/how-to-shift-side-bar-ubuntu-dock-to-bottom-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-later). You are using Ubuntu 18.04 which comes with GNOME instead of Unity, that's why that `gsettings set` command has no impact.

Comment: Also please avoid asking multiple questions in a single question. It is not supported here and questions with multiple questions are usually closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Gnome Tweaks and Dash to Panel from the Ubuntu store. Enable the panel extension from the Gnome Tweak, then change the panel position to bottom.

[image]

As to running the python installation script, make sure the script is executable before running it.

```
chmod a+x fslinstaller.py
./fslinstaller.py
```

Comment: Thank you! I did install Ubuntu Tweak tool, but it is not responding although I picked up the "bottom" position.

Comment: @user852814 Did you install dash to panel as well? I added a screenshot

Comment: No, I will try now as you advise!

Comment: @user852814 It lets you combine the dock and panel into one, and place them on the top, or on the bottom like windows 10.

Comment: Do you know how to solve also my second issue with FSL :)

Comment: @user852814 I've just updated my answer above; that's probably is your problem.

Comment: I must be missing sth very obvious as it doesn't work. It says chmod cannot access fslinstaller.py: No such file or directory, althouth the " .py file" is in my downloads

Comment: Can you see the file when you do a "ls -l"? make sure you cd to the right directory first.

Comment: You are so nice!!! Thank you a lot! It turns out I was not even in the directory! I just started with Ubuntu today! Thank you a thousand times!

Comment: Good luck, 18.04 is a very nice version to get started.

Comment: Using "Dash to panel" just to move the dock to bottom is an overkill TBH.