# Ubuntu won't register dock settings changes in 18.04

Tags: settings, dock, ubuntu-dock

In the GUI settings I previously moved the dock to the bottom of the screen. Now I can't move it back to the left of the screen. The change appears in the settings window, but nothing actually happens to the dock, even after reboot.

Comment: What happens if you try the command-line solution from the second answer here: https://askubuntu.com/q/966927/480481

Comment: Thanks, pomsky. I tried the command via terminal and it doesn't work. So it's not a GUI issue.

Comment: I figured it out. I downloaded the Gnome Tweaks program and it must be overriding the settings. When you turn off "Dash to panel" the dock can be moved around again.

Comment: Where is the "Dash to panel" option? I am facing the same problem. Thanks.