# Dock setting does not work - Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock, gnome-control-center

I just upgrade to 18.10 from 18.04 and the dock is always hidden. I tried to modify the 'Auto-hide the dock' in Settings, but nothing works. I also tried to change the position (from left to bottom) and this also does not work.

Comment: Does [the command-line solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/966930/480481) for moving the dock to bottom work?

Comment: Do you have the `Dash to Dock` GNOME extension installed?

Comment: Nope, the command-line does not work.

Comment: Yes, I have installed dash-to-dock extension and it also does not work.

Comment: I have a similar issue, my dock stops autohiding after resuming my laptop from sleep. The command line does not work then. The only thing that works is restarting the session. The problem arose after updating to Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Session worked for me (Ubuntu 18.10.) In my case I added a second monitor, and dock setup stopped responding.

Comment: What does _restarting session_ mean?  I have exactly the same (always auto hide, position cannot be changed).  I've logged in/out many times, but this doesn't go away.

Comment: I do not remember the exact in-and-outs of the issue, but restarting a session would be to logout and log back in.

Comment: Ah.  That works!   This is a home machine that is always logged in and only rebooted after security updates.   Reboot doesn't help.  Logout and back in does.  Thanks!

Comment: please mark the answer up it this worked for you