# Place GNOME Dash to top of screen instead of left side

Tags: gnome-shell

On the home screen I would like to display the *Dash* (circled in yellow below) of the [GNOME Desktop Environment](https://wiki.gnome.org/Gnome3CheatSheet), the bar of applications, across the top of the screen instead of down the left side of the screen.
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: This documentation is about GNOME version 3.6. I think it's outdated.

Comment: @JenareYoshi Indeed! However, none newer was available at https://www.gnome.org/ and this will illustrate what the OP wants to change from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move Ubuntu dock to bottom on Ubuntu 17.10 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966927/how-do-i-move-ubuntu-dock-to-bottom-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-later) See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966930/480481). It would work with a vanilla Ubuntu flavour (version 17.10 and later). It doesn't merge the top bar and the dash, but just moves the dash (and dock) from left to top.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dash-to-panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) [GNOME Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/) does precisely that. Here's one example after it's installed: 
[image]

Install it and [GNOME Tweaks](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/) (required to enable it) using the terminal with the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel`

Log out and then back in. Then open Gnome Tweaks

[image: GNOME Tweaks icon]

where you will see the extension, and you can enable it there.